# Unable to install 'wrtc' package while trying to run the serverless-webrtc code : https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc. The error log is below

Tags: node.js, webrtc

> 10923 error Linux 3.16.0-41-generic 10924 error argv "node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" 10925 error node v0.10.25 10926 error
>   npm  v2.11.2 10927 error code ELIFECYCLE 10928 error wrtc@0.0.56
>   install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` 10928 error Exit
>   status 1 10929 error Failed at the wrtc@0.0.56 install script
>   'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'. 10929 error This is most
>   likely a problem with the wrtc package, 10929 error not with npm
>   itself. 10929 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   10929 error     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build 10929 error
>   You can get their info via: 10929 error     npm owner ls wrtc 10929
>   error There is likely additional logging output above.